# Finding different rows in two separate excel files in different columns and combineing them

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am completely new to this so I don't have any code to present.

I need help with python 3.x, preferably the pandas package.

I have two separate excel files. In the first excel file I wanna find rows by the value in them, the value looks like `K232999`. They are located in the second column.

Then I wanna use the time value that is associated with those names, which is in the first column and is in format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`, and use it to find rows in the second excel file and extract them. The time values in the second file are also in the first column and have the same format.

On top of it the time interval is also important:

I need the interval from `1.9.2019. 12:55 - 2.9.2019. 10:35` and `2.9.2019. 09:46 - 3.9.2019. 02:51` for `K324645` and then find same intervals in different excel file and combine them in separate excel, or somewhere in memory so I can use them, or preferably both. For example:

Excel 1:

```
1.9.2019. 12:55 K324645
1.9.2019. 17:55 K324645
2.9.2019. 02:51 K324645
2.9.2019. 10:35 K324645

2.9.2019. 12:55 FGJFJKH
2.9.2019. 17:12 SAFFAFA
2.9.2019. 19:15 SGDFGDS

3.9.2019. 11:46 K324645
3.9.2019. 17:55 K324645
3.9.2019. 20:51 K324645

3.9.2019. 05:32 FDSJFJKH
3.9.2019. 10:12 SAFFAFA
3.9.2019. 17:12 SGDFGDS
```

Excel 2:

```
1.9.2019. 12:57 345,7
1.9.2019. 17:50 218,3
2.9.2019. 02:53 323,4
2.9.2019. 10:29 125,5

2.9.2019. 13:00 215,8
2.9.2019. 17:09 232,7
3.9.2019. 09:53 188.7
3.9.2019. 10:45 656.5

3.9.2019. 12:26 355,2
3.9.2019. 17:45 656.5
3.9.2019. 20:49 268.4
```

Final result:

```
1.9.2019. 12:55 K324645 345,7
1.9.2019. 17:55 K324645 218,3
2.9.2019. 02:51 K324645 323,4
2.9.2019. 10:35 K324645 125,5 

3.9.2019. 11:46 K324645 355,2
3.9.2019. 17:55 K324645 656,5
3.9.2019. 20:51 K324645 268,4
```

Note that the dates are different in the tables. I have to extract values from the seconde within the time frame of first.

Comment: you need read excel using pd.read_excel and then use pd.merge

Comment: Ok, but I need to filter out specific time intervals that are related for specific code. And the data is really big

Comment: Hello, welcome to the community, kindly read: 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. That would help us to recreate your problem to find a solution

Comment: use how = 'inner'

Comment: Could you please give an example. I literally just started, and just a hint is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First use:

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.read_excel(file1)
df2=pd.read_excel(file2)

pd.to_datetime(df1['Time_Column_name'].str.strip(),format='%H:%M:%S')
pd.to_datetime(df2['Time_Column_name'].str.strip(),format='%H:%M:%S')
```

then merge the 2 dataframes using:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,how=inner)
```

Comment: please use `df.loc[df['column_name'] == K324645]` to filter rows

Comment: I'm sorry but how can I extract rows from a seconde excel file with this

Comment: `df2=pd.read_excel(file2)' This will extract rows from 2nd file

Answer (score 0):

You say you are completely new, so I am not sure how far you have gotten with this.  If you have imported both files into dataframes, then you need to rename your `DateTime` column in both dataframes to the same name. Then use an inner merge.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='DateTime', how='inner') # merge the dataframes
df3['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['DateTime']) # convert column to date/time format
```

At this point, I would separate the dataframe into two. One with time between 1/9/2019 12:55 and 2/9/2019 10:35. The other for times between 2/9/2019 09:46 and 3/9/2019 02:51. Then merge those two back together.

```
firstset = df3[(df3['DateTime'].astype(str) >= '2019-01-09 12:55:00') & (df3['DateTime'].astype(str) < '2019-02-09 10:35:01')]
secondset = df3[(df3['DateTime'].astype(str) >= '2019-02-09 09:46:00') & (df3['DateTime'].astype(str) < '2019-03-09 02:51:01')]  
final = pd.concat([firstset, secondset]).drop_duplicates()
```

This should accomplish what you want. It might not be the quickest way, though.

Comment: Ok, but how can I extract time interval from 1.9.2019. 12:55 -  2.9.2019. 10:35 and 2.9.2019. 09:46 - 3.9.2019. 02:51 from the second excel file?

Comment: Adjusted the code to handle that. If this accomplishes what you want, please accept this answer.

Comment: Also, you may need to reset your index.  ```final.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, this is not a valid solution. The link between the tables has to be the timeframe. When I type in K324645 in real lifeI'll get a time frame from a - b, c - d, e - f and so on. I wanna use that time frame as a link through which I'll search the seconde table and extract values within the time frame. Note that the time frames are random, very random and there is a lot of them.

Comment: actually, the more accurate time frame would be a - b, f-h, m-r

Comment: The first edit had the times in both dataframes matching, so I could just merge on that column. Now it is edited where the days match, but not the times, so I can't do an inner merge. I will probably not get a chance to work on this for a few hours, but think I can knock it out. Just to be clear, the only data you need to keep is what is between the two time frames you listed? If so, we can filter this out first, then merge. Though it will still need some more work in between to match them up.

Comment: Yep, I changed it because I realized it is a bad example, sorry about that. Yes, the only time that I need is in two-time frames, but bear in mind that these time frames are just an example. In reality, I have a lot of time frames, and I have a lot of codes. So it has to be flexible. When I type different code it will have a bunch of different timeframes that I'll use for extraction. Yes, the date is the same, but the time is never the same that's why I need time range.

Comment: OK, I think I have this, but there's something I don't understand. Your df1 has ```1.9.2019. 12:55 K324645``` and ```1.9.2019. 17:55 K324645```. Your df2 has ```1.9.2019. 12:43 345,7``` and ```1.9.2019. 17:50 218,3```. Both have the same day but different times and, of course, the times do not match. So how are we supposed to know that ```1.9.2019. 12:55 K324645``` matches to ```345,7``` and not ```218,3```? Is it just supposed to map to the one closest in time? Also, is it aways two time frames (starta - enda) & (startb - endb) or can there be only one or even more time frames desired?

Comment: Or, does it not matter which one it is mapped to as long as both ```345, 7``` and ```218, 3``` both get pulled and matched to ```K324645```?

Comment: Out of excel one, we extract two-time frames, 1.9.2019. 12:55 - 2.9.2019. 10:35 and 2.9.2019. 09:46 - 3.9.2019. 02:51. The goal is to get every minute from 12:55-10:35 and 9:46-2:51. And the look in excel 2 for everything that lives in that interval.

Comment: There can be hundreds of time frames.